# Where is previous substitute saved?

Tags: vim

Well, previous search is saved in `/` register, and can be cleared with `let @/=""` but if you press <kbd>n</kbd> after that it fills `/` register with my last substitute command. Where is last substitute saved? How can I clear it?

Comment: What is the purpose of clearing the last substitute pattern? If you set any other search pattern (other than `""`) than the substitute pattern will never be used again.

Comment: Well, the purpose is if some ocpd guy ask me how to do so I'll have an answer :D actually my problem is I have hlsearch command in my vimrc and I have a map for nohlsearch, but when I run this shortcut and source my vimrc highlight activates again because the hlsearch command in my vimrc activates, so I got curious if it's possible to remove the search history completely or not.

Comment: You can use `histdel()` to delete search history but it doesn't seem to remove the last substitute pattern. It sounds like you want to restore the last search in your mapping.

Comment: yeah I wanna restore the last search in my mapping. Actually I overcame my problem by adding a variable and checking its status in vimrc, but I'm just curious if there's a way to remove substitute history or not.

Answer (score 2):

after you execute `:s/pattern/rep/` command, the `@/` will be set with `pattern` again.

That's why pressing `n` works.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain the exact problem, I substitute something (`:s /patternt1/rep/`) then register `/` gets value "pattern1", then I search for something like "pattern2" by pressing "/" and then typing "pattern2" and then hitting "return" and register `/` gets value "pattern2" then I run let `@/=""` and register `/` gets empty. Then I press "n" and register `/` gets value "pattern1". I want to be able to make vim forget previous substitute value like previous search value.

Comment: @Sassan I took a look vim source, after `:s` command was executed, it saves the `RE_SUBST` pattern, but I didn't dig into it, if it could be managed by vim user. https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/ex_cmds.c#L4451

Comment: Thanks, now the question is how to change RE_SUBST variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

@kent Thanks for looking in the code. I'm not sure if this will set RE_SUBST. I found

```
:he viminfo-/
```

which says the / value can be set to zero which I think will have the desired effect. To see the value you have set:

```
:set viminfo?
```

If it's not in there already

```
:set viminfo+=,/0
```